# How can I use for statement inside 'RPM spec file'?

Tags: bash, rpm, rpm-spec

I tested below is working well on shell. I'd like to update this on spec file. Get filename of all filenames existing inside some folder

```
for filename in testfolder/*.txt; do
   filename =${filename %.txt}
done
```

Comment: this should not work with the spaces inside your code...

Comment: @ChrisMaes, I'd like to wonder how could I uses these types of command inside spec file. It's sample code, I checked it's working well on shell

Comment: your question is not clear. What do you want to do? It depends on where you want to use this in your spec file.

Comment: Try to give us a real reproducible example: what you want to obtain, what did you try, what output do you get, what output did you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All SPEC sections but `%files` and preamble are shell scripts. You can use it there without a problem.